# C# TabPage Почему не показывается Image?

Tags: c#, winforms

В TabControl Добавляю ImageList

```
ImageList _imageList = new ImageList(new Container());
_imageList.Images.Add(Resources.alert_16_px);
_imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
_imageList.ImageSize = new Size(16, 16);
TabControl1.ImageList = _imageList;
```

Затем во вкладке выставляю ImageIndex:

```
tabPage.ImageIndex = 0;
```

В результате картинка не отображается, но текст сдвигается как будто должна отобразиться картинка:

[image: Сдвинутая вкладка]

Пробовал использовать Image.FromFile("1.jpg") вместо Resources.alert_16_px, пробовал разные картинки, разного расширения - картинка так и не показывается.

Когда вывел эту картинку на вкладку как BackgroundImage - все отображается.

Следовательно проблема не в картинке.

Не могу понять почему не отображается картинка если она есть в TabControl1.ImageList

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Remarks**
>
> Because setting the `ImageSize` property causes the handle to be recreated, 
>   you should set `ImageSize` **prior** to setting the Images property.
>   When the handle for the `ImageList` has been created, setting the
>   `ColorDepth` or `ImageSize` properties in code, after setting the `Images`
>   property, will cause the collection of images set for the `Images`
>   property to be deleted.
>
> **Замечания**
>
> ... свойство `ImageSize` следует устанавливать **до** добавления изображений
>   в свойство `Images`. ... в противном случае, ранее добавленные
>   изображения будут удалены в момент назначения свойств `ColorDepth` или
>   `ImageSize` ... Это связано с пересозданием хэндла компоненты.

Comment: Исправил - это не изменило ситуацию.

Comment: @95vsb - значит, Вы неправильно исправили.

Comment: Вообще убрал установку ImageSize и ColorDepth. Не помогло